# Adding Facebook Pages Search Directory to Website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Are there any methods of adding something like the existing Facebook Pages directory to a website?

Directory can be found here: https://www.facebook.com/directory/pages/

I am currently using the Facebook API in my Rails app and I have a way to eventually solve this problem. However, it requires requesting access from Facebook and getting approved which will take a bit of time and adding the search might be a better option for my implementation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to implement a Facebook Page search on your website is the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search

You do NOT need to get approved for that, you only need an App Access Token. See the following links about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Ah that is actually perfect. I can change up the flow and use youre prescription. Thanks!